# Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 broke javascript debugging

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, javascript-debugger

Ok I have just updated to Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. They are very excited about their updates to the debugger. However I am having nothing but headaches with it.

Before Update 2 I could set breakpoints in my .js files and run in IE and I would be able to break and debug within the IDE.

Now when I try and add a breakpoint to any .js file it immediately opens up the [dynamic] file and places the breakpoints. If I restart or refresh the breakpoints are lost and I have to reset them only for them to be erased again when I refresh.

This seems to be effecting only the .js files that are being called within the app. I have an SPA built on Durandaljs and Knockoutjs. In this instance it is a Modal that I am trying to break inside its viewmodel.

If I place breakpoints in one of the root page files, the breakpoint will persist but it still switches over to the [dynamic] file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our team we experienced those problems that you mention plus other ones. In addition to this there was a general slow down in the IDE. Update 2 RC was not stable enough and we went back to Update 1.
We will be waiting for the official release to be out to try again.

So that was our takeaway: never try a non official update of VS again.

But maybe here people would suggest another solution.

Comment: Yes I found the same. Unfortunately even uninstalling and reinstalling didn't even work for me. Nuget became broken and I had to refresh the pc fully. I agree fully don't install update 2

Comment: Yes after the RTM I did update.  I actually had such problems with the RC than I refreshed my PC fully, and put a fresh install of VS on my system.  After updating everything works as expected.  There are allot of great new additions and well worth the little issues that pop up here and there.

Comment: We're having massive hangs when hitting errors in js files from typescript. Vs.net will take 3-5 minutes to become responsive again before showing the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
(IIS Express -> right click -> Exit)
```

`OR`

```
(Ctrl + F5)
```

This delete all loaded files in IIS Express and will prevent load [dynamic] files.